# Powermockito how to call ProcessBuilder redirectError(File file)

Tags: java, powermockito

I have a class which calls
ProcessBuilder redirectError(File file)

I want to do the powermockito of this, but i am getting always null pointer exception.

My method in the class is

```
void sample() {

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("command")
builder.redirectError(new File("test");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To mock a class which are instantiated in a method local, use whenNew() of powermockito.

```
final ProcessBuilder processBuilder = PowerMockito.mock(ProcessBuilder.class);
PowerMockito.whenNew(ProcessBuilder.class).withArguments(Matchers.anyString())
    .thenReturn(processBuilder);
```

Add below annotations on your test class.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest
```

In prepareForTest annotation, add the classname that is having your sample() method.